# How to use closures to create event listeners in a Javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures, addeventlistener

HTML

```
<span class="char" id="0">?</span>
<span class="char" id="1">!</span>
<span class="char" id="2">"</span>
<span class="char" id="3">/</span>
<span class="char" id="4">%</span>
<span class="char" id="5">$</span>
...
```

JavaScript

```
var charElems = document.getElementsByClassName('char');

for (var i=0; i < charElems.length; i++) {

    charElems[i].addEventListener('mouseover',function() {

        (function(j) {mouseoverCheck(j);}(i));

    });

}
```

I have a bunch (hundreds) of `span` elements with numbers as IDs (starting from 0 and incrementing by 1).  What this loop is supposed to do is create mouseover event listeners for all the `span` elements (which all have a class of `char`).  Once moused over, it should excecute the `mouseoverCheck()` function and pass in whatever `i` was when that event listener was created.  So the 203rd event listener should pass in `203`.  But it does not.  Right now, it passes in what I believe is the last value `i` was before the loop completed.

I was attempting to use an IIFE and closure to make sure each event listener got `i`'s value at the time it was created, instead of it's value when the function is called.  Clearly, I didn't do it correctly, but I am fairly certain closure is the key to my problem.  Can anyone shed some light on how to do this properly?  I thought I understood closure, but clearly I do not...

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/5wg835m6/

Comment: If all you truly need is the index number, I wouldn't use a closure. I'd just put the index directly on the DOM element: `charElems[i].__index = i;` and then  use `mouseoverCheck(this.__index)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it doesn't work because

```
charElems[i].addEventListener('mouseover',function() {

        (function(j) {mouseoverCheck(j);}(i));

    });
```

`addEventListener()` is just assigning a handler and by the time that handler is called `i` will be 6.

you should return a handler from an IIFE

```
var charElems = document.getElementsByClassName('char');

  for (var i=0; i < charElems.length; i++) {

      charElems[i].addEventListener('mouseover', (function(temp) {

        return function(){
             var j = temp;
             //mouseoverCheck(j);
             console.log(temp);
       }
    }(i)));
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qshnfv3q/

Comment: There are some syntax errors in provided fiddle. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/5wg835m6/

Comment: @RayonDabre i forgot to update the changes ,thanks for the pointer

Comment: So it turns out my misunderstanding was with how event listeners work, and not closure!  This has solved my problem, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
var charElems = document.getElementsByClassName('char');

for (var i = 0; i < charElems.length; i++) {

    //close...
    //charElems[i].addEventListener('mouseover',function() {
    //    (function(j) {mouseoverCheck(j);}(i));
    //});

    //like this
    (function(el, x) {
        el.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            mouseoverCheck(x);
        });
    })(charElems[i], i)


}
```